# Convert to CHAR value in a CASE statement that returns different data types

Tags: sql, oracle, select, case

I have a working query as follows:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2, 
    CASE 
    WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT col3_typeID) OVER (PARTITION BY col1) = 1
    THEN col3_typeID   <-- this is what interests me

    WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT col3_typeID) OVER (PARTITION BY col1) > 1
    THEN COUNT(DISTINCT col3_typeID) OVER (PARTITION BY col1)
    END 
    COUNT(col4) OVER (PARTITION BY col1)
    FROM table
  -- joins
  -- other conditions
```

I count something, and if `COUNT() = 1`, then I return an `ID` instead of a number of those IDs. Ideally, I'd like to return the CHAR value of that `ID`. If I attempt to replace the marked line above with a column of type `CHAR`, I get

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER
```

I've also tried `DECODE()` as :

```
 THEN DECODE(col3_typeID, 1 , 'type1'
                         2,  'type2' )
```

But I get the same error, naturally, as this is a basic datatype restriction.

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the branches of a `case` expression need to return the same datatype - in your case, a `char`. You could achieve this by explicitly converting the number in the second `when` branch to a `char` too:

```
CASE 
WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT col3_typeID) OVER (PARTITION BY col1) = 1
THEN col3_typeID -- Assume this is a CHAR column

WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT col3_typeID) OVER (PARTITION BY col1) > 1
THEN TO_CHAR(COUNT(DISTINCT col3_typeID) OVER (PARTITION BY col1)) -- Here!
END
```

Comment: Works! I wish I could think outside the box a bit more sometimes. Will accept when possible. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing unrelated types (`CHAR` and `NUMBER` as the error message states) in your `THEN` and/or `ELSE` clauses. Although some database convert them automatically, standard conforming database is not required to do so.

Therefore, you should `CAST(number AS CHAR(1))` where appropriate.

Find the full story in an article I wrote on that:

- http://modern-sql.com/feature/case#data-type

Answer (score 0):

The type of each CASE must be convertible to the same type.  You are attempting to return a CHAR in the first case and the result of COUNT(), a bigint, in the second.

You can A) coerce them to the same type (CAST) or B) return a record with both results.